# How to publish a command line script to npm

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts

I programmed a node script which I would like to publish to npm.
I want to be able to install it globally on my system and execute it using
`scriptname args`. Currently, I'm running the script using `node scriptname.js args`
How can I do this? How do I have to link my script inside the package.json for npm to find/use it, and do I need to export something inside my script.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the "bin" section of package.json ? See more here: [package.json#bin](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin)